# Tcl/Tk: how to get the cell index of text widget by mouse clicking

Tags: text, tcl, tk-toolkit

In my Tk project, I display a data table in `text` widget as following:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
a b c d e f g h 
A B C D E F G H`


Now I want to add a new function: by clicking the text I can get the position index (which row and which column)? 
So is it possible to release such effect in Tk? If possible, can you share some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your mouse click binding, you'll have the `%x` and `%y` of where the click happened. You can use those with the text widget's [`index` method](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M121) to translate into `line.column` form.

```
bind .txt <Button-1> {
    puts "Click was at [%W index @%x,%y]"
}
```

A lot of the time, just using the [`@`***x***`,`***y*** form](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M26) of indices is good enough.